# Write an invocable apex class to remove characters from a string

Tags: apex, string, invocable-method, replaceall

Fairly new to Apex so please bear with.

I am trying to write a simple Apex Class that makes use of the replaceAll function to remove unnecessary characters from a string.

I've got as far as the following:

```
    public class ReplaceApex {
    @InvocableMethod(label = 'Regex Replace' description = 'Get rid of unwanted characters' category = 'User')
  public static List<String> regexReplace(List<RegexReplace> regexReplace) {
    RegexReplace r = regexReplace[0];
    String regexResponse = r.replaceAll('[^A-z0-9?-]','');
    List<String> ret = new List<String> {regexResponse};
    return ret;       
    }
    public class RegexReplace {
    @InvocableVariable(required = true)
    public String question;
  }
}
```

But I am getting the error:

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void replaceAll(String, String) from the type ReplaceApex.RegexReplace

How do I get around this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replaceAll method is available for string class

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_string.htm

You are trying to use this method on RegexReplace  class which does not exist. hence facing this error.

**Solution**

1. Mostly it seems like you want to remove characters from question
   based on regex. So replace

> `String regexResponse = r.replaceAll('[^A-z0-9?-]','');`

with

> `String regexResponse = r.question.replaceAll('[^A-z0-9?-]','');`

2. Or you can implement replaceAll method in RegexReplace class

Comment: You are a star! Thank you!